# Trigger a PHP function through a HTML button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a **conmysql.php** with this function:

```
function addTeacher($idTeach,$nameTeacher,$teacherDay){


    $adicionar = sprintf("INSERT INTO `test`.`teacher` (`$idTeacher`, `$nameTeacher`, `$teacherDay`) VALUES ('$idTeacher', '$nameTeacher', '$teacherDay');");
    $queryadd  = mysql_query($adicionar);
}
```

I'm filling these variables with 3 forms, and it's working but i don't know how to trigger the addTeacher (); on a HTML button.

I should use AJAX? If yes, how?

Comment: dont need ajax,, submit form to page that handles the submitted values

Comment: `I should use AJAX? If yes, how?` google it

Comment: Yes, i have no problems with this but i just don't know how to trigger the function that sends the values to the MySQL using a HTML button.

Comment: JS/HTML cannot trigger a call to a php function. you need to use ajax or post/get request and handle this in your php page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1):

Try like,

**HTML**

```
 <input type="button" id="addTeacher" value="Add teacher"/>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function(){
    $('#addTeacher').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
           url:'conmysql.php',
           type:'POST',
           data:{type'addTeacher','name':'ABC','day':'day to add'},
           success:function(data){
              alert(data);
           }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
function addTeacher($idTeach,$nameTeacher,$teacherDay){
    // Id of teacher should be primary and autoincrement 
    // so there is no need if teacher id
    $adicionar = sprintf("INSERT INTO `test`.`teacher` (`$idTeacher`, `$nameTeacher`, `$teacherDay`) VALUES ('$idTeacher', '$nameTeacher', '$teacherDay');");
    $queryadd  = mysql_query($adicionar);
}

if(isset($_POST['type']) and $_POST['type']=='addTeacher')
{
  addTeacher(1,$_POST['name'],$_POST['day']);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i must be doing something wrong, but when i click the "Add Teacher" button, nothing happens.

Comment: @PatrickMaia I tried to show you the way not the full code, you should find your own way or edit the `question` with some new `problem` or what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can't call PHP functions from HTML.

You'll need to think of a solution where your HTML triggers the PHP page to run, one common method is to use AJAX to do this, although you could also do it in a form submit, it's up to you.

Comment: in other words, you need to build a REST API (your php file receives POST or GET request via your client page's js)